# Error in twitter streaming

Tags: twitter, apache-spark, streaming, twitter4j, spark-streaming

I am writing a twitter connector using spark streaming. 
I am facing the follwing exception

> ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting
>   receiver with delay 2000ms: Error starting Twitter stream -
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at   org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStart(TwitterInputDStream.scala:89)
>        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:121)
>        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply$mcV$sp(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:159)
>        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:152)
>        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor$$anonfun$restartReceiver$1.apply(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:152)
>        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
>        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
>        at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
>        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Below is the relavent code snippet.

```
val config = new twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder()
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("*********************")
               .setOAuthConsumerSecret("**********************************************")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("****************************************************")
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("**********************************************************")
    .build

val twitter_auth = new TwitterFactory(config)
val a = new twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization(config)
val atwitter : Option[twitter4j.auth.Authorization] =  Some(twitter_auth.getInstance(a).getAuthorization())

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterPopularTags").setMaster("local[*]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
// ssc.checkpoint("D:/test")
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, atwitter, null, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)

val hashTags = stream.map(status => status.getUser().getName())
hashTags.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreach(println)
})

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to the line where the exception is thrown, we can see:

[if (filters.size > 0) {](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/twitter/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/twitter/TwitterInputDStream.scala)

For that line to throw a NPE, filters has to be null, which is exactly what's happening on the instantiation of the TwitterStream:

> val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, atwitter, **null**, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)

Being `filter` a sequence, initialize it with `Seq()` instead of `null`.